# Subgroups of finite index have finitely many conjugates

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

is it true the following statement:

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. If the index $[G:H]$ of $H$ in $G$ is finite, then $H$ have finitely many conjugates.

What I think, is that it's true. I proceed as follows:

Suppose $[G:H]=n<\infty$ and let $\{g_{1}H,\dots,g_{n}H\}$ be its left cosets. For every $g\in G$ there exists a unique $1\leq i\leq n$ such that $g=g_{i}h$ for some $h\in H$. This implies that $gHg^{-1}=g_{i}Hg_{i}^{-1}$. So there can be at most $n$ conjugates of $H$.

Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks right to me.

Comment: Your proof is correct, but you have not proved that $H$ has finitely many conjugacy classes, which is obviously false in general. You have proved that $H$ has finitely many conjugates in $G$.

Comment: $gHg^{-1}$ is not a conjugacy class of $H$, it is a conjugate of $H$.

Comment: @Derek Your absolutely right. I confused the concepts. I have edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Antonio why did you accept egreg's answer but not upvoted it? Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proof is correct, up to a minor detail.

You know that $gH=g_iH$, so
$$
gHg^{-1}=g_iHg^{-1}
$$
However, $g=g_ih$ for some $h\in H$, so $g^{-1}=h^{-1}g_i^{-1}$, so
$$
gHg^{-1}=g_iHg^{-1}=g_iHh^{-1}g_i^{-1}=g_iHg_i^{-1}
$$

This is, however, just the observation that $xH=yH$ if and only if $Hx^{-1}=Hy^{-1}$, so maybe you had already this implicit in your proof.